# Positioning input inside ons-toolbar

Tags: html, input, position, toolbar

I need to put search-input inside ons-toolbar and it must be placed (streached) inside left-center range. how can I do it properly?

Answer (score 0):

```
display: inline-block
float:left
max-width: 300px (whatever you want)
```

Comment: i've already tried that but it is not working properly. except when i declare fixed width. but it is not satisfactory because the screen size changes depending on the device and orientation. when using ons-toolbar input must be inside div class (left, center or right). search-input must take all available space... like in facebook app on iphone

Comment: can you take a screenshot of what the expected result should be?

Comment: I found a solution. in the event that someone is interested:

<div class="left center right">
                <ons-row>
                    <input type="search" class="search-input" style="margin-top: 6px; margin-left: 6px; max-width: 80%">
                    <ons-toolbar-button>
                        <ons-icon icon="ion-navicon" style="font-size: 32px; width: 1em"></ons-icon>
                    </ons-toolbar-button>
                </ons-row>
            </div>